# W: Failed to fetch Mongo 3.2 file

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates, update-manager, mongodb

I am trying to install Mongodb on my remote scaleway server. I am following the steps given in [Mongodb official document](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).

Although i had installed on other remote servers using the same link, i am unable to install on my remote scaleway server. The moment i add the key and list file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, I am getting the following error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/trusty/mongodb-org/3.2/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'multiverse/binary-armhf/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How to deal with this?

Comment: The repositories support only amd64 and i386. No ARM support.

Comment: That was very informative, thank you. But can you guide me as to what has to be done for mongodb to be installed in that server?

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#production seems to have ARM64 builds for 3.4 and Ubuntu 16.04. Other than that, I suppose you'll have to build from source.

Comment: Since i am required to install Mongo v3.2 on Ubuntu 14.04, i cant follow the above guidelines. But if you link me about building from source i can look up to it.

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/wiki/Build-Mongodb-From-Source